# Why does it never enter in a for loop?

Tags: c

This is my first time asking a question on stack overflow. My switch statement which switched on an enumerated type inputted by the user is only working for case: QUIT . Here is my code:

```
int get_function(menu_t get_input)
{
    int i;
    double rad, result;


    switch ( get_input )
    {
    case Sin:

        i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i > loop_limit; i += step_size)
        {
            rad = PI * (i /180);

            result = sin(rad);

            printf("\tsin(%d) = %.4lf\n", i, result);
            printf("\n");
        }


    break;

    case Cos:

        for(i = 0; i > loop_limit; i += step_size)
        {       
            rad = PI * (i /180);

            result = cos(rad);

            printf("\tcos(%d) = %.4lf\n", i, result);
            printf("\n");
        }


    break;

    case Tan:


        for(i = 0; i > loop_limit; i += step_size)
        {
            if(i <= 75)
            {   
                rad = PI * (i /180);

                result = tan(rad);

                printf("\ttan(%d) = %.4lf\n", i, result);
                printf("\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\ttan(%d) is UNDEFINED", i);
            }
        }


    break;

    case QUIT:

        printf("You chose QUIT. Thank you, come again!\n");
    break;


        }
    return(0);
}
```

As you can see I'm using for loops inside the cases that aren't executing... is this the problem? Thanks to anyone who can help me with this...

Comment: because `loop_limit` is `0`? please learn how to use debugger

Comment: The loop conditions are backwards. They should be `i < loop_limit`. I'm voting to close as a simple typo.

Comment: loop_limit is defined as 90...

Comment: here is the menu_t definition:

Comment: typedef enum 
{
 Sin,
 Cos,
 Tan,
 QUIT
}menu_t;

Comment: i want the for loop to include 90, so made the for loop count by increments of step_size until it exceeds 90

Comment: If loop limit is 90 then the for loops say "i equals 0.  Now loop as ling as i is larger than 90.  Wait! it isn't.  don't do anything"  Did you mean `i<=loop_limit`

Comment: `for(i = 0; i > loop_limit; i += step_size)`,here if the loop limit is defined as 90 then condition never satisfies your condition is `0>90` check that

Comment: oh, that makes sense.

Comment: in this code both loop_limit and step_size could be negative

Comment: thanks everyone, that was absolutely the problem. I had my loop test condition backwards. Much appreciated

Comment: you switch case statements are executed. If you cannot use debugger you can add printf() as first statement of every case and you will see that depending on the value of menu_t you will "fall" into the corresponding case. It is good habit always to add "default" - it protects you against the future re-designs of your code.

Comment: You don't need a separate `printf()` to print an additional '\n' character, e.g., `printf("Hello world!\n\n)` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your for loops.
With this writing :

```
for(i = 0; i > loop_limit; i += step_size)
```

You will set *i = 0* and ask the work being done as long as *i > loop_limit*... so, never.

The correct writing is :

```
for(i = 0; i <= loop_limit; i += step_size)
```